# Azure Subscription Cmdlet

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-cmdlet

I'm trying to manage an Azure SQL Datawarehouse, specifically pause it in the evenings when nobody is using it.  I've downloaded, logged in, and can successfully mange other resources using PowerShell ISE.  However, when I go to pause the instance it says invalid Resource Group.

When I call Get-AzureRmResourceGroup only a few show up, at least 8 are missing.  Everything is visible in the azure portal.

Comment: This probably isn't the case but is there any chance some are in a different subscription that you take for granted when viewing via the portal? If so, you can use `Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId xxx` to look at the other subscription.

Comment: Yes, I tried calling Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId {id} with both of my subscriptions.  I also called Get-AzureRmResource, but only one of the subscription's resources get listed regardless of which subscription ID I use

Comment: What permissions does the account you are logging into Azure have? are you sure this isn't a permissions issue? what do you see from the Portal with the same account?

Comment: I see everything when I log in using the same account in the Portal.

Comment: @DavidMcSpadden You said you tried `Select-AzureSubscription` but did you try `Select-AzureRmSubscription`?

Comment: @Jaxidian that was it; can you submit as answer.  Just in case anyone else gets here: Select-AzureRmSubscription does not show up in the right hand Command tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId xxx` (not `Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId xxx` - note the "RM" in the middle of the correct call) should allow you to specify the appropriate subscription to see the resources you're looking for with `Get-AzureRmResourceGroup`.

[More info on Select-AzureRmSubscription.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt619459.aspx)